# NASM - Number to big ASCII-Matrix

Tags: assembly, matrix, ascii, nasm

I would like to print numbers in bigger **ASCII-Matrices** with a NASM-program. Like a dot-matrix-display but only with ASCII-Characters. In my program, I can just display one number, but I fail to display two numbers in one row.

```
section .data

four: dw 0xdb,0x20,0x20,0xdb,0x0A,0xdb,0x20,0x20,0xdb,0x0A,0xdb,0xdb,0xdb,0xdb,0x0A,0x20,0x20,0x20,0xdb,0x0A,0x20,0x20,0x20,0xdb     ; 4 in ASCII-Signs

   fourlen equ $-four

 section .bss

    a1      resw 200           ;space to store the ASCII-Matrix-Numbers

section .text
global _start

_start:

    mov eax,four
    mov [a1],eax                ;first 4 in a1

    mov [a1+fourlen],eax        ;second four in a1

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,[a1]                ;display 44 -> fail
    mov edx,200
    int 80h

end:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

I want to store every ASCII-number in `a1`, to be able to display the ASCII-numbers in a single row. But that fails. Any help/tips to realise that?

Comment: You are copying pointers when you should be copying a chunk of data. But I see more problems with your code. I think it would be best for you to post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ruud: This isn't on-topic for Code Review.  The OP is reporting problems and is not requesting a review (and we only review working code).

Comment: @Jamal: Thanks for clarifying. I hope my answer below will be of help to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reserve a buffer of 200 words, so I suppose you have got the intention to copy the entire block of data from `four` to `a1`. In assembly, this is not going to be done by a single `mov`.

Your instructions copy two *pointers* referencing `four` into `a1`:

```
mov eax,four
mov [a1],eax                ; first 4 in a1
mov [a1+fourlen],eax        ; second four in a1
```

Instead you should copy the *contents* of `four` into `a1`:

```
cld
mov edi,a1         ; destination address
mov esi,four       ; source address
mov ecx,fourlen    ; number of bytes
rep movsb          ; copy data from source to destination, first time
                   ; do NOT adjust edi; it's already at the right address!
mov esi,four       ; same source address
mov ecx,fourlen    ; number of bytes
rep movsb          ; copy data from source to destination, second time
```

In line with this, you should direct *sys_write* (i.e. your first `int 80h`) to `a1`, not to the first of the two pointers you originally stored in `a1`. So instead of:

```
mov ecx,[a1]
```

do this:

```
mov ecx,a1
```

Additional remarks:

- You should only output what you copied; replace `mov edx,200` by `mov edx,2*fourlen`.
- You will notice the visual position of the second 'four' is not correct. How to fix this, depends on whether you want to print horizontally or vertically. If you want the second digit underneath the first one, then you should add a trailing `0x0A` to `four`. Or preferrably two `0x0A`s, to keep some space between the two digits. If you want the two fours to be on the same line, then you will have to append some ANSI escape codes to `four` to move the cursor up 4 lines, to compensate for the 4 linefeeds in `four`. If you do not want to use escape codes, then you will have to refactor your code so that it writes all digits together, line by line.
- One might consider `a1` a waste of memory, and copying your data there a waste of CPU time. You might as well use two separate print calls, straight from `a1`. Whether you actually want to do this depends on your choice concerning my previous remark.
- You are using 16-bit words to store characters, which is fine if you want your output to be UTF-16-encoded. The terminal window on my system expected UTF-8; some more adjustments were needed there.